# Prerequsite checking in WIX installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

i want to set prerequisite for my installer. The prerequisite is that installer should check whether either 18.0.0.5 or 16.0.0.3 versions of installer is installed in the machine.
I tried by writing an entry to the INI file by adding a header "Avalialbleversion = 18". And wrote custom action in the new installer to Kill install if this version is not there.The  prerequisite checking was working as expected and the only problem is that if i uninstall either 18.0.0.5 or 16.0.0.3 header "Avalialbleversion = 18" will still be there in the INI file. Is there any other better way to implement this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is to add an entry into the [LaunchCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369752(v=vs.85).aspx) table. Combine this with the [AppSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367579(v=vs.85).aspx) or [RegLocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx) table.